# IOS Calling Phone number with using * and # add in number

Tags: ios, phone-call, openurl

In iOS i want to call calling dial pad when I am tried to a normal number and using + and - symbols then it's working good, but when I am trying to add * and # Tag then call dial is not open. Please give me solution how can i do this

Here is My CODE

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:@"*123*12335553#"];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```

Comment: Replace `*` with `%2A` and `#` with `%23`

Answer (score -1):

Please replace your character : `[<your string> stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@""];` from your string.

Comment: It is meaning less then !!!